# Filtering through 2 differents components after rendering them

Tags: vue.js

I'm stuck with this problem : I'm trying to order 2 same-level components who both have their own datas with their own properties. But the 2 differents datas have the same "position" property.

DB structure

**Chapter**

`chapterId`

`title (string)`

`position (integer)`

**Page**

`pageId`

`name (string)`

`position (integer)`

`body (text)`

Here is my **Summary.vue**

```
<template>

  <div>

   <summary-chapter v-for="chapter in data.chapters" :chapter="chapter"></summary-chapter>

   <summary-page v-for="page in data.pages" :page="page"></summary-page>

  </div>

</template>
```

The data variable is :

```
data : 
{
   'chapters' : { {chapterId: 1, ...}, {chapterId: 2, ...}, {chapterId: 3, ...}, ... },
   'pages' : { {pageId: 1, ...}, {pageId: 2, ...}, {pageId: 3, ...}, ... }
}
```

I'm looking for this kind of results : Mixed

`Pos: 1 - Page with id of 12`

`Pos: 2 - Chapter with id of 7`

`Pos: 3 - Chapter with id of 2`

`Pos: 4 - Page with id of 4`

`Pos: 5 - Page with id of 13`

`Pos: 6 - Chapter with id of 1`

But I always have all chapters first and then all pages :

`Pos: 2 - Chapter with id of 7`

`Pos: 3 - Chapter with id of 2`

`Pos: 6 - Chapter with id of 1`

`Pos: 1 - Page with id of 12`

`Pos: 4 - Page with id of 4`

`Pos: 5 - Page with id of 13`

I really have no clue how to do it the right way.
I tried to filter through a computed data property
I try dto built a parent component *Summary row* taht contains a *chapter component* or a *page component* depending on the type
I try 100 other ways ... :(

Do you guys have a tip ?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Louis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this problem is combine those two arrays then sort by its position:

```
computed: {
  sortedItems () {
    let chapters = this.chapters.map(chapter => ({ ...chapter, type: 'chapter' }))
    let pages = this.pages.map(page => ({ ...page, type: 'page' }))
    return []
      .concat(chapters)
      .concat(pages)
      .sort((a, b) => (a.position - b.position))
  }
}
```

Then in you template render it by type:

```
<template v-for='item in sortedItems'>
  <summary-chapter v-if='item.type === "chapter"' :chapter='item'/>
  <summary-page v-if='item.type === "page"' :page='item'/>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I finally got the good sorted datas with your solution. The problem was that I couldnt display it properly. Your template solution is not working. I had to put the loop to the <summary-chapter> with the v-if and had to put v-else on the <summary-page> then i wrapped both component with a <div> and it worked ! thanks a lot. I let you Edit your answer to vote it as the GOOD answer

Comment: You are right, there's some typo in my example code but the concept should works. https://codesandbox.io/s/v3wx5zq4l0.